# Get only date from "date" type column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to select value from "date" type column. I have there value like 29.04.2019 but when I select it and print in view I get 29.04.2019 00:00:00.

My query:
`SELECT Id, project_name, start_date, end_date, Team_Id FROM Projects;`

Comment: if you're getting a time too, then your column `start_date` and `end_date` aren't the `date` datatype. Seems like they are a `smalldatetime` or `datetime2(0)`. In fact, if you have `.`'s instead of `-`, then you are probably using an `(n)varchar` to store the values, If so, you need to fix that, `varchar`, is not the correct datatype to store dates in. Use a date(time) datatype. Using a `varchar` will only cause problems, and solve none.

Comment: Column code: ` [start_date]          DATE          NOT NULL,`

Comment: Since you mention `asp.net`: there isn't a `Date` type in .NET, only `DateTime`. So when you get your values from the database in a .NET app, they are converted to `DateTime`; you'll have to format them in your app then.

Comment: A `date`, doesn't have a time portion, @SebastianSiedlarz. This sounds like the issue is your display layer then, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `DD.MM.YYYY` format use `CONVERT(varchar(10), Getdate(), 104)`

```
SELECT Id, project_name, CONVERT(varchar(10), start_date, 104) as start_date,
CONVERT(varchar(10), end_date, 104) as end_date, Team_Id FROM Projects;
```

all sql format [check the link here](http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_SELECT-Formatting_Date_Time.php)

Answer (score 1):

use `Convert` function to convert datetime to date

```
SELECT Id, project_name, convert(date,start_date) start_date, convert(date, end_date)end_date, Team_Id FROM Projects;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, project_name, 
convert(date,start_date) as start_date, 
convert(date,end_date) as end_date, 
Team_Id FROM Projects
```

Comment: Hi! Please add an explanation to the solution as code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Thanks! --From Review.